# How to add Column titles to a dataset without any in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have these two datasets.

! curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msu-cmse-courses/cmse202-S21-student/master/data/Dataset.data

! curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msu-cmse-courses/cmse202-S21-student/master/data/Dataset.spec

So I read the data in using

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Dataset.data", header = None)

Then I want to make column titles for the Dataset.data since it doesn't have any, just the rows with the data for each snail.

I tried using

data.columns = ['sex','length','diameter','height','whole_weight','shucked_weight','viscera_weight','shell_weight','rings']

to add it to the data set but it gives me the error:

Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 9 elements

Can anyone help me I just want my data to have these column titles in it. Currently it has no column titles just numbers

Cheers.

Comment: It seems your `data` dataframe has just 1 column. What is the outcome of `len(data.columns)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is delimited by space, but `read_csv` defaults to comma, so you need to specify the delimiter manually:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('Dataset.data', delimiter=' ', header=None)
data.columns = ['sex','length','diameter','height','whole_weight','shucked_weight','viscera_weight','shell_weight','rings']
data.head(2)
```

|  | sex | length | diameter | height | whole_weight | shucked_weight | viscera_weight | shell_weight | rings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | M | 0.455 | 0.365 | 0.095 | 0.5140 | 0.2245 | 0.1010 | 0.15 | 15 |
| 1 | M | 0.350 | 0.265 | 0.090 | 0.2255 | 0.0995 | 0.0485 | 0.07 | 7 |

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I was stuck for over an hour. You're the best lol such an easy fix I'll look out for it next time.